# What causes static in a coffee grinder's receptacle?

Tags: coffee, grinding

What causes static in a coffee grinder's receptacle?

The question of how to reduce static has been asked multiple times on cooking SE (see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&q=coffee%20static). However, I can't find a legitimate answer as to why ground coffee has static build up. Some discuss moister in the beans, but how is that related to static?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know anything about burr grinders, but with blade grinders you generally get tiny bits of coffee bean being spun quickly around the outer edge of a plastic enclosure. This is a recipe for generating static electricity by the [triboelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect), the same as rubbing a balloon on your hair or shuffling your feet across a polyester carpet.